# How to use Xcode 4 mergetool in a standalone fashion?

Tags: xcode, git, merge

I sometimes have to make git merges on the console. Up until now, for resolving conflicts, I was using Xocde 3's FileMerge (you can open it on the console using the 'opendiff command'). If conflicts show, I use 'git mergetool' which automatically invokes opendiff for each of the conflicting files.

However, when I perform pulls on Xcode 4 and there's a conflict, a much nicer mergetool is used (which I believe it is part of the Xcode 4 executable). It allows you to preview the result in real time, and manually edit merges on case-by-case basis, which is a very useful.

Is there any way to use the Xcode 4 mergetool when using 'git mergetool'?

I cannot find an executable for this tool inside the Xcode 4 bundle. Any hack that achieves this would be welcome.

Comment: Do you want to open mergetool using opendiff? Is that what you are looking?

Comment: Nope. I believe that opendiff (or filemerge, which is the actual name of the program) was used for merges on Xcode 3.x. On Xcode 4.x a completely revamped merge component is used. The main difference is that this new merge component allows editing of the resulting file while you do the merge (while mergetool didn't). Also, it looks much nicer. I guess that using this new one in a standalone manner cannot be easily done, as it seems that the new one is deeply integrated with Xcode 4.x. Anyway, not that important now that Kaleidoscope 2 has been released (which has similar functionality).